# calculate percentage of elements on mongodb aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I have a Mongoose Dataset Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa78cd3d2dcd60dc00f7c42"),
    "uid" : "5aa1205d52725521e48f4e93",
    "net" : 301,
    "total" : 400,
    "score_percentage" : 0,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-03-13T09:17:31.521Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I want to Calculate the Percentage of net value from total Value.

Desired Result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa78cd3d2dcd60dc00f7c42"),
    "uid" : "5aa1205d52725521e48f4e93",
    "net" : 340,
    "total" : 400,
    "score_percentage" : 40,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2018-03-13T09:17:31.521Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

For that I will aggregate the mongodb Query but not getting the Result. What I Implemented is :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
                {$match: { "uid": "5aa1205d52725521e48f4e93"}},
                {
                    $addFields: {
                                            score_percentage: { $divide: [ { $multiply: ["$net", 100]}, "$total" ]}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $out: "collectionname"
                }
            ], function(error, data){
                console.log(data);

//It will return 85% i.e 340*100/400;
//But I want to treat this as 100 like: 340 will be 40 and 400 will be 100.
//So desired result will be like 40%
});
```

Any Help is really appreciated.

Comment: How do you get to 40%?

Comment: how `340*100/400 = 40%?` is there any other criteria to calculate? or you have used random value for example@Abhay

Comment: Calculation criteria will be like 0 to 100. So We treat net value as starting point of zero and total value i.e 400 treat as 100. Like simple calculation is 45*100/100 = 45%